Continue a directory tree checksum from a given file
I have:

A checksum.txt file which contains many lines of checksums of single files from a mountpoint in a huge directory, which mounted and then it disconnected, thereby not finishing the checksum.txt (partial checksums)
localchecksums.txt full checksum list, containing thousands of lines of SHA256 checksums with filenames etc.

I would like to:

Compare the remote mount checksums and local ones with sha256sum -c checksum.txt localchecksum.txt or similar, but:


I don't want to go through gigabytes of data again to get the remaining hashes
I don't want to restart the whole process for checksum.txt

I generated the list by using find to recursively find single files and exec sha256sum on them.
It is possible to get the remaining hashes by comparing the two files or somehow continue checking the checksums by reading the checksum.txt file and only calculating checksums for unchecked files. The problem with the first approach is that the order is different in the files. The second approach sounds good but I don't have any idea how to start with that.
Sample of any of the checksum files:
8e2931cc1ad3adc07df115456b36b0dbd6f80f675e0a9813e20ad732ae5d4515  ./folder/8ggSHp5I7hNEl3vDCbWv6Q/wA-KzXIh1Ce3G93s20X24v_4vUeywBe3mXPhGjPt_Lg/cRf8KgbqIsqwbon3DX3PN1-oV6_Nr9Baeymaw-ZJw00
37d2dfe2315cc401536329e3fbe421384bbb50c656c3dbeb42798e5666822e6c  ./folder/8ggSHp7I7hHEl3vDCbWv6Q/wA-KzXIh1Ce3G93s2oX24v_4vUeywBe3mXPhGjPt_Lg/V02s6HKhyJ9Nyd2jQtSjWg
d0e9b95065a264db0d372ccace5d3a72f38f74ca7b44da4794dae23c91e18e57  ./folder/8ggSHp7I7hNxl3vDCbWv6Q/wA-KzXIh1Ce3G93s2oX24v_4vUeywBe3mXPhGjPt_Lg/U3fhBugX6pexYzh6qGKlW7lYWsFShWH7JwN9fmU8ay2lLZkciH2sXsiGbmIc97iJ
44a5fe29063e472857bb9a1929af06a32bb4b2394630f80c2dc732fd662620bc  ./folder/8ggSHp7I7hNEc3vDCbWv6Q/wA-KzXIh1Ce3G93s2oX24v_4vUeywBe3mXPhGjPt_Lg/gTrqUL4ZjWTWMl6BcjfwUe5bBDatscwUoYY9IFQDztc



Just use mtree.  It's exactly for this kind of thing.

@JimL. how fast is it? would it need to download all the files for local computing just like sha256sum needs? (not that efficient) My goal is compare whether all the files and folders are identical (I omitted the folder requirement due to it being not that important in the question)

In principle,

sort the list of file names already with a checksum
find and sort a full list of file names
use comm to obtain the set of files that aren't yet processed (files in one set that aren't in the other)
generate sha256sum checksums for files in the resulting list

Demonstration (bash not sh):
based=/etc                      # Directory base
csums=/tmp/etc_checksums.txt    # Checksums file

# EXAMPLE ONLY
# TAKE CARE NOT TO OVERWRITE YOUR REAL DATAFILE WHILE TESTING !!
# Generate a partial set of 30 checksums
find "$based" -type f |
    head -n30 |
    while IFS= read -r f; do sha256sum "$f"; done >"$csums"


# USEFUL WORK
# Identify the set of differences
LC_ALL=C comm -13 <(sed 's/^[^ ]*  //' "$csums" | LC_ALL=C sort) <(find "$based" -type f | LC_ALL=C sort) |
    # For each missing item
    while IFS= read -r f
    do
        # Generate a new checksum and append it to the checksums file
        printf '%s' "$f" >&2
        sha256sum -- "$f" >>"$csums" && echo >&2
    done

This code will work for file names containing whitespace, but will fail on pathological file names containing newlines and other non-printable characters. (No doubt others can suggest how to bullet-proof the code if that's really required.)
Test carefully before modifying your original checksums file. Ensure that $based matches your original starting point so that the comm can correctly filter out duplicates.

So basically find fetches the folder and file paths for the checksums or how does it work? I'm guessing I don't need the # EXAMPLE ONLY part because I already have a partial checksum file, is that correct?

You can use the "example only" section as a try out. It generates checksums for only 30 of the files under /etc, so that the remainder of the code can generate the rest. Just ensure you're not overwriting your real checksums file, @SirMuffington

Thanks, I'll look into it soon ;-)

is it possible to restrict the amount of connections made by find to certain number? It seems to error out for me...

What's your exact find command and what is the error message?

The find command is from the script and the error is Input/output error from find. This might help me https://serverfault.com/questions/6709/sshfs-mount-that-survives-disconnect because I have a hard limit on the connections I can make and find builds up a new connection each time I use find, and I don't find a way to restrict that

The serverfault link did not help it still errors out :(

Input/output error typically means a hardware issue. Unfixable from software; at best you can skip the inaccessible files or filesystems

"is it possible to restrict the amount of connections made by find" - er, "connections" doesn't really mean anything here: there's one instance of find iterating across the filesystem. That's all it's doing

Not an hardware issue per se. On the cloud provider there's a hard limit of connections (I would assume in the firewall rules) and find exhaust the connections quickly. I mounted the cloud storage via sshfs if it matters

find simply traverses the directory tree

then there's a hardware limit for I/O or similar, even though the cloud provider denies that and points to the certain limit of simultanous connections allowed
